# Applying lambda on Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am having a Python Pandas DataFrame like

```
>>> df
  classification like 
0         flower    1 
1         flower    0 
2         flower    0 
3      adventure    1 
4      adventure    1
```

I want to create an output DataFrame like

```
>>> df
  classification like  liked
0         flower    1  True
1         flower    0  False
2         flower    0  False
3      adventure    1  True
4      adventure    1  True
```

I am "apply"ing the Python lambda function on the input DataFrame as follows:

```
>>> df['like'].apply(lambda x: x == 1)
```

But I am getting all 'False' under the 'liked' column

```
>>> df
  classification like  liked
0         flower    1  False
1         flower    0  False
2         flower    0  False
3      adventure    1  False
4      adventure    1  False
```

Any quick suggestions will be helpful.

```
>>> df['like'].astype(int)
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
Name: like, dtype: int32
```

@jezrael

```
>>> df['liked'] = df['like'].astype(bool)
>>> df
  classification like  liked
0         flower    1   True
1         flower    0   True
2         flower    0   True
3      adventure    1   True
4      adventure    1   True
```

@jezrael : DTypes

```
>>> df.dtypes
classification    object
like              object
liked               bool
dtype: object
```

Comment: try `df['like'].astype(int)`

Comment: If you can avoid `apply` which is a hidden loop as your needs can be vectorized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert integer column to boolean:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'like']))
<class 'numpy.int64'>

df['liked'] = df['like'].astype(bool)
```

Or assign comparison with 1:

```
df['liked'] = df['like'] == 1
```

If `1` is string compare by string `'1'`:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'like']))
<class 'str'>

df['liked'] = df['like'] == '1'
print (df)
  classification like  liked
0         flower    1   True
1         flower    0  False
2         flower    0  False
3      adventure    1   True
4      adventure    1   True
```

Comment: When I compared using df['like'] == '1' it is working. But the problem is when I checked the data type for the 'like' column it is showing as int32

Comment: Do you check it by `print (type(df.loc[0, 'like']))` ?

Comment: No I checked by df['like'].astype(int)

Comment: Here is possible check it by `print (df.dtypes)`, it return `object` for string column